# Fill ComboBox with Linq from MS Access

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access, combobox

I'm new to C# and Linq and want to fill a `ComboBox` with Linq from MS Access. But if I debug the code, the `ComboBox` is empty.

I read some older posts but they didn't help. Where is the failure?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        label1.Text = "OK";

        PoolDataSet pool = new PoolDataSet();

        comboBoxPool.DisplayMember = "Pool-Name";
        comboBoxPool.ValueMember = "ID";

        comboBoxPool.DataSource = (from x in pool.Pools
                                      select x._Pool_Name).ToList();

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Move the `comboBoxPool.DisplayMember = "Pool-Name";
                comboBoxPool.ValueMember = "ID";` to the under of this line: `comboBoxPool.DataSource`.

Comment: Then, I am getting a exception of "Cannot bind to the new display member"...

Comment: Did you cut and paste that two lines or just copy them?

Comment: And also you can't bind `ComboBox` to fields, your code should be like this `comboBoxPool.DisplayMember = "_Pool_Name";`

Comment: Tried both variants copy/cut. Same problem. Get the same failure when I change to DisplayMember = "_Pool_Name";

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, to fill my pool-Object was the problem. I got it with adding .Fill() :

```html
connection.Open();
connectionLabel.Text = "Connection successful!";

PoolsDataSet pool = new PoolsDataSet();
(new PoolsDataSetTableAdapters.PoolsTableAdapter()).Fill(pool.Pools);
comboBoxPool.DataSource = (from x in pool.Pools
                           select x.ID).ToList();

comboBoxPool.DisplayMember = "ID";

connection.Close();
```

It's running ;)